# Access - Create Select Statement via Excel Template

Tags: vba

to export data from an Access 2010 Database I would like to use an Excel template as seen below.

[image]

In the first row I can define columns that are in the database. In the second line I can define exactly 1 filter which will be used in the "where" statement.

When pressing a button in Access, a query that is based on the defined columns and filters should be executed and the result will be exported to the Excel.

I am honest, I am not that skilled in VBA. What would be the best point to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way too broad and as such it should not even be here, but let me give you some points to look at.

1. First you'll need to get your data from the Excel file. If you are not skilled with VBA, then the easiest way would be opening it through VBA using an `Excel.Application` object and `Workbooks.Open` method, and get your values from your `Range`.
2. Create an SQL Select statement from your values.
3. Do not use just a `SELECT` query, make it a `SELECT INTO` query (a "make table query" as Access likes to call it). That way your results will be inserted into a (new) table, making it easier to output.
4. Export your new table to Excel. There are several ways to do this, search for `DoCmd.OutputTo` or `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.